# Different compression settings for different qrc files

Tags: qt, qmake, qresource

Some qml files benefit from compression quite a lot (source files), others do not (already compressed data like png or mp3).

The resource compiler itself can specify the compression level for each resource file when invoked manually.

Is it possible to specify different compression settings for different qrc files in the .pro file?

I've tried:

```
QMAKE_RESOURCE_FLAGS += -threshold 0 -compress 9 # set for all qrc files
QMAKE_RESOURCE_FLAGS += -no-compress icons.qrc # make an exception
```

However, that format doesn't seem to be correct, as I am getting an error:

```
rcc.exe:-1: error: File does not exist 'icons.qrc'
```